# Hide "Tunnel to" sessions

Tags: fiddler

I try hide sessions generated by social part of Chrome. But hiding of traffic marked as "Tunnel to" in host column not working. Althoungh I successfully hide another sessions based on hostname patterns.

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "y";
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") will match all of the "Tunnel to" requests.

Comment: My problem were: above rule not match "Tunnel to" but @OCary solution solved it.

Comment: The rule suggested by OCary does *exactly* the same thing as the code snippet above, assuming you put that snippet in one of the event handlers.

Comment: @EricLaw Didn't worked for me : I still see `Tunnel to` : https://i.imgur.com/UXcrQhu.jpg ( already restarted)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try the menu option *Rules* -> *Hide CONNECTs*

Comment: Doesn't hide the 407 Tunnel To

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks.